# How to save a graph as an a4 size pdf file under windows system? (R; ggplot2)

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

How to save a graph as an a4 size pdf file under windows system? 
In R, it's easy to save a graph as a pdf file, but how to save it as an a4 size file?

Answer (score 36):

```
pdf("a4_output.pdf", paper="a4")
```

And if you want A4 to be the default pdf size, so that you don't need to keep on specifying it:

```
pdf.options(paper = "a4")
```

The above works for default R plotting, for ggplot you need to use the `ggsave` function. I'm not sure if ggplot has built-in paper sizes, but you can specify dimensions in any units with `ggsave`, so for A4 you can do:

```
ggsave(file="a4_output.pdf", width = 210, height = 297, units = "mm")
```

Comment: thank you! But when it is grid.arrange plot, the ggsave won't work.

Comment: what function do you use to save the plots normally in your situation?

Comment: @baptiste How do you get this working on ggsave with arrangeGrob?

Comment: `ggsave('filename.pdf', arrangeGrob(qplot(1,1)), width=4)`

Comment: For me this gives a paper size slightly smaller than A4 paper. The resulting paper size is 209.90 mm x 296.69 mm, instead of 210 mm x 297 mm of an A4 paper.

Comment: Might have to play with the DPI parameter to get it exactly right I suppose.. anyway this answer is super old, I'd be surprised if they haven't added support for A4 yet

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this, and found out that I needed the correct `device` (`cairo_pdf`) to print all text correctly. Works with `grid.arrange` too.

For portrait:

```
ggsave(filename="yourfile.pdf", 
       plot = yourplot, 
       device = cairo_pdf, 
       width = 210, 
       height = 297, 
       units = "mm")
```

For landscape:

```
ggsave(filename="yourfile.pdf", 
       plot = yourplot, 
       device = cairo_pdf, 
       width = 297, 
       height = 210, 
       units = "mm")
```

Or, with `dplyr` you could use:

```
ggplot(...) %>%
  ggsave(
    filename="yourfile.pdf", 
    plot = ., 
    device = cairo_pdf, 
    width = 210, 
    height = 297, 
    units = "mm")
```